# print 30 digits of a double value in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

My understanding is that numeric_limits::max_digits10 gives the max number of digits after the decimal point that are available. But if I setprecision() to a value that is greater than this, it still gives me nonzero digits beyond this max value :

```
assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10 == 17);
std::cout << std::setprecision(30) << double(.1) << '\n';
```

This prints out:

```
0.100000000000000005551115123126
```

Are the digits beyond 17 not to be trusted to be accurate?

Comment: Required reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Double is defined as 1.7E +/- 308 (15 digits) So you can go up to 308 digits for some numbers. But read what @ThomasMatthews suggested first.

Comment: Accuracy of `double` is not fixed like ±10^(-17), it depends on value of the number. Bigger values have worse accuracy, smaller numbers - better. In other words, ±error of value is is determined relatively to the value. As you can see, error for number x is about ±0.00000000000000005 * x

Comment: A blog with far too much information on floating point: http://www.exploringbinary.com/tag/floating-point/

Comment: "non-zero digits" is not the same thing as _meaningful digits_.  The floating point "digits" that are stored in the variable are not decimal digits at all:  They're binary digits; and there's no guarantee that the process of converting binary to decimal will only give you zeros after it runs out of useful information to work with.

Comment: 17 decimal digits (e.g., 1.16 format) are sufficient for round-trip precision of an IEEE-754 double. There's *no* real reason to print out further digits. see: `std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10`. The digits beyond 17 in (0.1) are junk. Also consider  that (0.1) has no *exact* representation.

Answer (score 3):

Converting the 53 bit (leading 1 implied) mantissa of the double to binary fixed point:

```
0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

This equals the decimal value

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

which matches the question's result to 30 digits

```
0.100000000000000005551115123126
```

However what could be a 54th bit is unknown, and if you consider this as a range of possible values, the binary fixed point numbers just below and above would be

```
0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110001
0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110101
```

representing decimal values:

```
0.099999999999999984734433411404097569175064563751220703125
0.100000000000000012490009027033011079765856266021728515625
```

which implies 16 or 17 digits of precision. So the 30 digits of precision are only accurate if you consider the double precision number to be an exact representation rather than the closest representation.